# How to read Blob synchronously in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a chrome extension to intercept WebSocket traffic, by hooking the function `WebSocket.send`, like:

```js
var _send = WSObject.send
WSObject.send = function (data) {
    arguments[0] = my_hook_function(data)
    _send.apply(this, arguments)
}

function my_hook_function(data) {
    // how to read the data here synchronously?
    return data
}
```

The `my_hook_function` should be synchronous. The type of *data* is Blob, I can't find a synchronous API for reading the Blob. Google says there is `FileReaderSync` but I tried in console and this class does not exist.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a synchronous [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) in  client-side JavaScript. And you can't make it synchronous either. So instead you should make **everything** async.

Use the regular `FileReader` object and wrap it inside of a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).  By using [`async` / `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) you can wait for the file reader to be finished before continuing and sending over the value.

```
var _send = WSObject.send
WSObject.send = async function(data) {
  const result = await my_hook_function(data);
  _send.call(this, result);
};

function my_hook_function(data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = ({ target }) => resolve(target.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    reader.readAsText(data);
  });
}
```

Sidenote: If `WSObject.send` expects a single argument, then the [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method will suffice. It's similar to [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) with the only difference that `.call` expects one or more arguments to pass, and `.apply` an array of arguments.

Also, try to avoid the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object and use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Synchrounous XHR  can help, but it is deprecated in main thread. You may use `URL.createObjectURL`, `XMLHttpRequest#overrideMimeType` to achieve that. see CodePen snippet [FileReaderSync equivalent for main thread](https://codepen.io/fuweichin/pen/QWzyeRe?editors=1111)

Another approach is to migrate to web worker and use `FileReaderSync`.